# Kibana Link multiple dashboards

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I am working with the elastic stack (logstash, kibana) and I would like to know if it is possible to have a "link" between two different dashboards.

Explanation : 
I have a dashboard "Movies" and in it I have all the movies in my library. I would like **click** on "let's say **pie chart**" , I am expecting a way to be **redirected** to the dashboard of this clicked movie. Is it possible ?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a navigation menu using the markdown widget to link dashboards to each other.

If you follow to this link: demo.elastic.co/

You can see that there is a dashboard component which allows you to click through various dashboards. Edit that component by clicking on the pencil icon and you can see the simple syntax of creating something like this.

As far as I know this is the only way to link dashboards together and create a navigation experience.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the other way to add links and open new dashboard:https://thenewstack.io/inserting-links-kibana-dashboards/

We can edit the format of a mapping by going to Management -->index patterns  and select the desired attribute for which you want to create link then click on edit symbol.

Now change the format detail to URL: provide the url of the dashboard you want to open here ensure that you change the url according to the desired selection of attribute using {{value}}

like for eg if this is the dashboard url: http://**********query:(language:lucene,query:'clientip:52.99.80.95')

then you need to change it something like:http://**********query:(language:lucene,query:'clientip:{{value}}')

put the above url in URL Template ,select Type as Link and label template as {{value}} and click on save.